# Web Intelligence : limit row number in a block

Tags: business-objects, webi

I have a list of events with a number of orders. I want to only display the first five biggest amount of orders in my report. I created a variable with the rank of each event :

```
=Rank([Total orders])
```

[image]

Then I created a variable with the five event depending rank but I get this :

```
=[Event] Where ([Rank]<=5)
```

[image]

I have an empty cell equal to all non displayed results and the sum of commands amounts.
Is there a way to fix that ? If it's not possible how can I rename the empty cell with "Others" label ?

I work on WebI 4.2 Support Pack 4 Compilation : 14.2.4.2410.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three different ways to do this. As an example I created a query using the eFashion universe.

[image]

1. You could create a variable like you had and add a filter where **MyRank <= 5**.

> MyRank=Rank([Query 1].[Quantity sold])

2. You could right-click on your **Orders** column, choose **Ranking > Add Ranking...**, and change the value for **Top** to 5. Leave everything else alone and click **OK**.

[image]

3. You could database ranking within your query. This option only brings back the data you want. The previous two option bring back more data than you want from the database and then filter it out in the report. This link has some further detail on how to set this up.

[image]

Each option has its place. The first one is most like what you have tried. I think the second one is the simplest. And the last one is the most efficient. You choose what is best for you.

Here are my results for each of the three approaches I described in order.

[image]